# Error connecting with SparklyR

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

I'm trying to follow the simple guide on [SparklyR](http://spark.rstudio.com/), but it throws me errors right at the very beginning. I install SparklyR and a local version of Spark as written in the guide:

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "1.6.2")
```

I then open a connection, and here's where the error occurs:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

I get "R code execution error" and the following:

```
Warning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at [... truncated]
2: In create_hive_context_v1(sc) :
  Failed to create Hive context, falling back to SQL. Some operations, like window-functions, will not work
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1686)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:598)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1480)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:195)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:94)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:55)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
```

Here is my session info:

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.0.136)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Swedish_Sweden.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2017-01-11                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version date       source        
 assertthat   0.1     2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 backports    1.0.4   2016-10-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 base64enc    0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 config       0.2     2016-08-02 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 DBI          0.5-1   2016-09-10 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 devtools   * 1.12.0  2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 digest       0.6.10  2016-08-02 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 dplyr        0.5.0   2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 httr         1.2.1   2016-07-03 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 jsonlite     1.2     2016-12-31 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 memoise      1.0.0   2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 R6           2.2.0   2016-10-05 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rappdirs     0.3.1   2016-03-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 Rcpp         0.12.8  2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rprojroot    1.1     2016-10-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 sparklyr   * 0.5.1   2016-12-19 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 tibble       1.2     2016-08-26 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 withr        1.0.2   2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 yaml         2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
```

Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do prior to following the guide?

Comment: Could you share the content of the `hive-site.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using Spark Version 1.6.2? Try

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "2.2.1")conf <- spark_config()

# create config file
conf$sparklyr.defaultPackages <- "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3" 

# connect
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", 
                version = "2.2.1",
                config = conf)
```